# Passing dynamic Variable IN WHERE statement IN SQL

Tags: sql, dynamic-variables

I have a WHERE statement where a DateOfService must be bookended between date ranges that could change.  Because of this, I build an IF statement to trap the conditions and build the BETWEEN part of the statement.

Here is a Sample:

```
IF ISNULL(@TargetStartDate, 'N') = 'N'
    BEGIN 
        SET @SubWhere = ' ad.EnrolledDate AND s.DateOfService'
    END ELSE BEGIN 
        SET @SubWhere = ' @targetStartDate AND  @TargetEndDate'
    END
```

When I incorporate into WHERE clause there is no visible error. The error appears on the execution of the ALTER PROC

Here is the snippet from the WHERE clause:

```
AND s.DateOfService BETWEEN CAST(@SubWhere AS VARCHAR(150))
```

Any insight as to how to get this to work error free are much appreciated!

Comment: This is a rather bad way of going about things, hard to get correct and maintain and prone to SQL injection issues if you're not careful. Try to write static SQL whenever possible and fold the conditions into it. I recommend [this series](https://sommarskog.se/dyn-search.html); the TL;DR version is [here](https://sommarskog.se/dyn-search.html#BasicStaticSQL). Also make sure that `DateOfService` is a `DATE` before you use `BETWEEN`, as you [really don't want to use `BETWEEN` with date/time types](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common).

Comment: Hi Jeroen, thank you for your comments.  I tried a CASE Statement with 

s.DateOfService >= <= the different date variables but WHERE CLAUSES don't like that either.

Comment: `CASE` does not seem useful here, no -- but you can write things like `WHERE (@TargetStartDate IS NOT NULL AND myColumn >= @targetStartDate AND MyColumn < @targetEndDate) OR (@TargetStartDate IS NULL AND MyColumn >= ad.EnrolledDate AND MyColumn < s.DateOfService)`, throwing in `OPTION (RECOMPILE)` as necessary for performance. (And yes, writing this stuff out is clunky, but that's the wonder of T-SQL. :P)

Comment: Thank you - I will try this!